# How to connect css animation with scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some images vertically. So when i scroll the scrollbar the center image should animate along with the scroll bar. that is, center image in the window should get bigger like zooming effect. How to do this?

Example: http://flashotaku.com/components/examples/carousel/carousel_ex10.html
In this example images at the edges are zoomed. but i need the center image to be zoomed - quite opposite like convex. How to do this? thank u.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/m7fcK/2/)

```
//code
.circle img {   
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: Try skrollr? http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: The example you gave uses Flash.

Comment: @Nunners i didn't find anything with jquery so i gave flash. so that u can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use jQuery .scollTop() function to get your vertical position.

Lets name it simply

```
var y;
```

So now if you listen to the scroll event you can use your y for very cool animations. 
In your project, I would compare y to ranges in which your pictures should be scaled big.
Something like:

```
if( circle.range.start < y < circle.range.end ) {
    //give circle the class to be scaled big
}
```

This is not working code. Sorry! I'm not having time at the moment. But maybe it gives you the idea to solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

It should try one of the following instead of implementing yourself.

http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/

http://julianlloyd.me/scrollreveal/

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/